# Python FFT outptut

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, python

I have a (real) array of data and am trying to analyze its frequency components. I've been using NumPy's FFT routines, but I realized there is something I don't quite understand: why does the output give me an imaginary part?

Of course I know that in general the Fourier transform is complex-valued, but it seems to me that the DFT is sampling frequencies that are integer multiples of the timestep of my original data trace. Shouldn't I then be getting results that lie only on the real axis?

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's still about the basic Fourier transform.  If all of your sinusoidal components were **cosine**, not *sine*, (which means that $x[N-n]=x[n]$), then all of your frequency components would be purely real, whether they are exactly an integer FFT bin location or not.  if all of the sinusoidal components were **sine**, not *cosine*, (which means that $x[N-n]=-x[n]$) then every frequency component in the FFT would be purely imaginary.  if the phase was somewhere between a cosine and a sine, then you will have non-zero real **and** imaginary parts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to analyze correlation/anti-correlation (in the frequency domain) of two different sets of data, so I am taking the Fourier transform of the cross-correlation function to try to get at cross-spectra, but I want to preserve potential anti-correlation so I don't want to simply take the magnitude of the FT. Are you suggesting there is a way I can modify the numpy function to get purely real frequency components? My data is very much non-periodic, so maybe what I'm trying to do is not even possible?

Comment: as rbj said, if your signal (in this case, the crosscorrelation) isn't even-symmetrical, then you get a complex spectrum; just looking at the real part of that is simply dropping half of the information. So, to answer your question: No, the result should not only lie on the real axis.

Comment: This article should give you an intuitive understanding of what a bin value means for a pure real tone in a DFT:  https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/768.php  If you "get it", and "it" follows directly from the definition, then you will understand why the imaginary part is intrinsic.  Note, this is not a common understanding, but it is a good one.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson  but look at this:  `fft(cos(2*pi*[0:3]/20))
ans = 3.3479 (0.1910 - 0.3633i) 0.2702  (0.1910 + 0.3633i)` So non integer DFT bin of cos yields complex result...

Comment: @Fat32 , ......hmmmmm.....

Comment: so, it doesn't have even symmetry about 0.  you don't have $x[-n]=x[n]$ (or more precisely $x[N-n]=x[n]$).  if you changed that 20 to 4 or 2 or 1 or 1/2, it would be the kind of cosine i mean.  or try this one: `fft(cos(2*pi*[0:19]/20))`

Comment: This goes back to one of my long-time complaints about MATLAB.  It's not just the *"1-origin"* indexing, it's the inability to do negative indices.  i wish we could just define the DFT and iDFT as:

$$ X[k] \triangleq \sum\limits_{n_0}^{n_0+N-1} x[n] \, e^{-j2\pi nk/N} $$

and

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{k_0}^{k_0+N-1} X[k] \, e^{+j2\pi nk/N} $$

where $n_0$ and $k_0$ can be any integers.  I would usually set them to be $n_0,k_0=-\left \lfloor \frac{N}{2} \right\rfloor$  .......

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes I think I remember your complaint about that MATLAB indexing... So I thought you were referring to MATLAB but oh sorry the question was about **python** my bad again !!!